# How to filter objects from one array from another array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have two arrays :

```
let channelList = [
  {
    "channelId": 1,
    "channelName": "SMS"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 2,
    "channelName": "EMAIL"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 3,
    "channelName": "ANDROID"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 4,
    "channelName": "IOS"
  }
]
```

and

```
let promoList = [
  {
    "id": 124,
    "channelType": "SMS"
  },
  {
    "id": 125,
    "channelType": "ANDROID"
  },
  {
    "id": 126,
    "channelType": "IOS"
  }
]
```

I want a new array `remainingChannels` which has

```
{
    "channelId": 2,
    "channelName": "EMAIL"
}
```

because it is not present in `promoList`, but it is there in `channelList`.

I am trying to get it using the filter operation like this:

```
for(let channel of this.promoDetailList) {
     remainingChannels = this.channelList.filter(e => {
         e.channelName == channel.channelType
     });
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: No, in this question there is array of characters. I have array of objects.

Comment: Just compare them by `channelName` instead. The logic for the array difference is the same otherwise.

Comment: VLAZ first comment is correct, just simplify one of the arrays of objects to a string array then follow the answer of that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let channelList = [{"channelId":1,"channelName":"SMS"},{"channelId":2,"channelName":"EMAIL"},{"channelId":3,"channelName":"ANDROID"},{"channelId":4,"channelName":"IOS"}];

let promoList = [{"id":124,"channelType":"SMS"},{"id":125,"channelType":"ANDROID"},{"id":126,"channelType":"IOS"}]

//Check if the `channelName` from `channels` is matching with any of the
//`channelType` from `promos` list, negate the result. 
const filterData = (channels, promos) => channels.filter(channel => !promos.some(promo => promo.channelType === channel.channelName))

console.log(filterData(channelList, promoList));
```

This can also be achieved using `Array.filter` and [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
let channelList = [{"channelId":1,"channelName":"SMS"},{"channelId":2,"channelName":"EMAIL"},{"channelId":3,"channelName":"ANDROID"},{"channelId":4,"channelName":"IOS"}];
let promoList = [{"id":124,"channelType":"SMS"},{"id":125,"channelType":"ANDROID"},{"id":126,"channelType":"IOS"}]

const filterData = (channels, promos) => channels.filter(({ channelName }) => !promos.find(({ channelType }) => channelName === channelType));

console.log(filterData(channelList, promoList))
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to using `!this.promoDetailList.some`?

Comment: Can also be achieved using `Array.find`, or `Array.filter` or `Array.findIndex`. I have updated my answer using `Array.find`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `Array.filter`.

```js
let channelList = [
  {
    "channelId": 1,
    "channelName": "SMS"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 2,
    "channelName": "EMAIL"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 3,
    "channelName": "ANDROID"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 4,
    "channelName": "IOS"
  }
]

let promoList = [
  {
    "id": 124,
    "channelType": "SMS"
  },
  {
    "id": 125,
    "channelType": "ANDROID"
  },
  {
    "id": 126,
    "channelType": "IOS"
  }
]

const result = channelList.filter(({channelName}) => {
  return promoList.filter(({ channelType }) => channelType === channelName).length == 0;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why are we using `({channelName})` like this here?

Comment: To compare the channelName value with promoList. So to check validation.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the items of one of the arrays into a string array.

```js
let channelList = [
  {
    "channelId": 1,
    "channelName": "SMS"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 2,
    "channelName": "EMAIL"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 3,
    "channelName": "ANDROID"
  },
  {
    "channelId": 4,
    "channelName": "IOS"
  }
]

let promoList = [
  {
    "id": 124,
    "channelType": "SMS"
  },
  {
    "id": 125,
    "channelType": "ANDROID"
  },
  {
    "id": 126,
    "channelType": "IOS"
  }
]

function cross(a, b) {
  const b_ = b.map(item => item.channelType)
  const res = []
  a.forEach(item => {if (!b_.includes(item.channelName)) res.push(item)})
  console.log(res)
}
cross(channelList, promoList)
```